# Removing multiple duplicate values spread through an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So this question has been asked before however I have seen it been asked to remove specific parts of an array.
The array I am working with has several duplicate values, some right next to each other and some not. My current code to filter it can filter the duplicate values that are right next to eachother, but not spread apart.

```
for(var i = 1; i<platforms.length;){
  if(platforms[i]==platforms[i-1]){
    removeItem(platforms,i-1);
  } else{
    i++;
  }
}
```

What do I need to change in order for the loop to look through the whole array and not just one value behind?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is putting your array in a Set, which is a constructor that does not allow for repeated values, and then spreading it out in an array again:

```
uniquePlatforms = [...new Set(platforms)]
```

Answer (score 0):

First off: This answer is using `for` loops only because the OP asked how to change his `for` loop for it to work (see note at the end).

---

You won't be able to do that with a single for loop because you need to keep track of the items you already processed.

```js
var platforms = ["foo", "bar", "bar", "baz", "foo", "quo", "foo", "quox"];

var len = platforms.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    for (var j = i + 1; j < len; j++){
        if (platforms[j] == platforms[i]){
            platforms.splice(j, 1);
            j--;
            len--;
        }
    }
}   

console.log(platforms);
```

**Note:** There are better ways of doing that (especially with >=ES6). For example with sets or filter functions.

Comment: Okay thank you! I was thinking about putting a loop within a loop I just wasn't sure how to organize it all.

Comment: @WesleyStokes Glad I could help! If my answer did indeed solve your problem, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it :)